# Start a JCL job automatically

Tags: jcl

I have a job which I need to be submitted at a specific time every day. I tried SCHEDULE and STARTBy, but it didnt work and I got a JCL error. I tried another jcl script which returned MAXRC zero, but nothing happened(MYJOB that was suppsed to start at a specific time didnt start)

```
//MYJOB1   JOB CLASS=A,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEBGENER
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=T
//SYSIN    DD=DUMMY
//SYSUT1   DD SYSOUT=(*,INTRDR)
//SYSUT1   DD DATA,DLM=XX
/*$TA10,T=15.10,I=86400,´$VS,´´s  JOB,N=MYJOB´´´
//XX
```

Comment: What scheduling programs do you use?  The problem I have here is that as is, I can't answer this.  I can tell you things that might help, and why what you're doing might not be working.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ou missunderstood the function of the `// SCHEDULE` statement. JES2/3 are *not* job schedulers, i.e. neither JES2 nor JES3 will *submit* a job. They process jobs submitted by other means such as manually by a (TSO) user, or automatically by a job scheduler program, such as IBM's IWS (formerly known as TWS), or BMC's Control-M.

The `// SCHEDULE` statement, valid on JES2 systems only, tells JES2 the relation this job has with other jobs, *which all need to be submitted to JES2 **by some other means**.* It may delay an already submitted job, or may increase its priority, but it *does not" submit anything.

Secondly, the `$TA...` command you issued through the job shown, will create an entry in the JES2 automated commands table, provided you are authorized to do so.

If you are authorized, JES2 will issue the MVS command `S  JOB,N=MYJOB` at the given time. *Note* that this is an MVS `START`command, which starts a started task (STC), or started job. It *does not* submit a batch job.

The JCL for this STC must be found in a PDS member called `JOB` in one of the system proclibs (`//IEFPDSI DD ...` in master JCL), or in one of the optional system job libraries (`//IEFJOBS DD ...` in master JCL).

I would say, the JCL error you received is because there is no member called `JOB` in either of the library concatenations.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunatly, //schedule didnt work for me.  So how should I change the abvementioned JOB to get the desired result?

Comment: @Soraya With JES2, you can't.  If you want to start a proc, which is a different thing than a job, at a given time, you can do that via $TA.  You can possibly have a proc that submits a job.  But chances are very good that you already have some sort of scheduling program in your shop, like Control-M or TWS, and you really should be using that.

Comment: @Soraya Can you answer Kevin's question regardind what job scheduler you're using at your shop?

Comment: unfortunately, I am completely novice in JCL, I was just asked to submit a JOB automatically, and I have no information about the SCHEDULER at my shop. How can I know what SCHEDULER we are using. Is there any way to find it?

Comment: If you knew what to look for, i.e. name of started tasks running on the systems, and how to relate those to products, you might be successful. But, being a beginner, you should ask your teacher, mentor, colleagues.